# Excel 2016 PowerPivot MDX query designer error

Tags: excel, powerpivot

When open Excel 2016, go to the Power Pivot tab, click the Mange button to bring up Power Pivot window

In Power Pivot, click Get External Data, choose From Other Sources

Choose Microsoft Analysis Services. Click Next

Fill in the SSAS server name, then click Next,

Click on the Design button, you may get the following error

Cannot load the query designer. If you contact Microsoft support about this error, provide the following message: Could not load type ‘Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.IErrorReportingService’ from assembly ‘Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91’..

Answer (score 1):

Looked at folder Excel is supposed to point to for searching for DLL – C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in\Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces.DLL.

Then looked at GAC folder – C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\

Renamed file to To Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces.OLD,

Then copied Microsoft.Datawarehouse.interface.DLL FROM
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in TO C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\
And it is working
for ref please visit
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2015/11/09/excel-2016-powerpivot-mdx-query-designer-error/